# Same Request, Different Results. (Chrome Extension vs Chrome Browser)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, request, fetch

I am currently working on a Chrome Extension. Because I was expecting difficulties, I made a beta Version in HTML & JS, sending request to a PHP script, which is working as expected.

Although I simply copied and pasted my code (with some small changes due to the nature of Chrome Extensions) it's not working anymore. The request is type JSON and includes priv_key and lv_number (and their key values).

The same request in the Beta yields different results in the Extension itself.

**SNIPPET OF BETA REQUEST**

```
function getFormData(data2submit) {
    event.preventDefault(); //Prevents Reload
    const status = document.getElementById("status"); // <p> to show status
    status.innerHTML="Request Sent";
    //get data that we need for the .json
    var privateKey = document.getElementById("PRIV-Key").value;
    var lv_number = document.getElementById("LV-Number").value;

    //create .json
    var formData = {
        "priv_key": privateKey,
        "lv_number": lv_number
    }

    //send data to sendFormData function
    sendFormData(JSON.stringify(formData));
}
function sendFormData(formData) {
    //function to send and receive data (and populate fields lateron)
    async function postData(formData) {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost/learneasy_js/lCheck3.php", {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: "same-origin",
            credentials: "same-origin",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            referrer: 'no-referrer',
            body: formData
        });

        const json = await response.json();
    }
    postData(formData);
}
```

**SNIPPET OF EXTENSION REQUEST**

```
function sendRequest() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function(result) {
    privKey = deobfuscate(result.key);
  });

  chrome.storage.sync.get(['lvnr'], function(result) {
    lvnr = result.lvnr;
  });

  var formData = {
    "priv_key": privKey,
    "lv_number": lvnr
  }

  formData = JSON.stringify(formData);

  async function postData(formData) {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost/learneasy_js/lCheck3.php", {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: "cors",
      credentials: "same-origin",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      referrer: 'no-referrer',
      body: formData
    });

    const json = await response.json();
    setInfo(json);

  }

  postData(formData);

}
```

I have compared the output of both bodies (formData) and they are, as far as I can see, equal.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Console?  Or in the extension?

Comment: No i'm currently trying to figure it out with php logfiles, dumping everything I send.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `chrome.storage.sync.get` is asynchronous which means that you're using the `privKey` and `lvnr` variables before they are set to the values in storage, here is how you can fix that:

```
function sendRequest() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(['key', 'lvnr'], function(result) {
    var formData = {
      "priv_key": result.key,
      "lv_number": result.lvnr
    };
    postData(JSON.stringify(formData));
  });

  async function postData(formData) {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost/learneasy_js/lCheck3.php", {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: "cors",
      credentials: "same-origin",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      referrer: 'no-referrer',
      body: formData
    });

    const json = await response.json();
    setInfo(json);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the solution to the problem <3